# How can I disable a button after when counter hits zero? C#,Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a feature that my button should only spawn a limited amount of objects.

I put a counter on the button so that it shows how many clicks are remaining until it reaches 0.

Then the count stops but the button is still active.

How can I disable the button after the count reaches 0, so that one can not spawn anymore objects.

I am using the code below to reduce the count.

Thanks for the help.

```
private TMP_Text _spawn;
private int _spawnAmount;

void Start()
{
    _spawnAmount = 2;
    _spawn = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
}

void Update()
{
    _spawn.text = _spawnAmount.ToString();
}

public void ReduceSpawnAmount()
{
    if (_spawnAmount > 0)
    {
        _spawnAmount--;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `button1.Enabled = false;` ??

Comment: this question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to make it non-interactable.

```
GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
```